# Opposites do not necessarily attract

Tags: etymology

What is the opposite of unmolested? Since molested seems to have an entirely different, unrelated meaning to being bothered. In Latin languages, like Spanish and Catalan, the verb "To Molest" generally means to bother someone.

Comment: Are you asking "What is the opposite of _unmolested_?" Or "Why is the opposite of _molested_ in English _unmolested_?" Or something else? The title that you give to your question isn't a question at all, but an assertion—which may have contributed to my confusion over what exactly you're trying to ask about.

Comment: Sorry about that. I rephrased my question to make it more clear. In any case, @Oldcat answered my question.

Answer (score 2):

The word **molested** does not exclusively mean having had unwanted sexual contact, rather the word is just being used as a euphemism for the act. Now this 'nice' meaning is driving the normal meaning, "having been bothered", out.

Thus molested really does mean the opposite of unmolested.